# Why doesn't my new tab show?

Tags: blocks

I just made a new tab (quicktabs) with the drupal interface, but it is not displayed like the other tabs. In fact, it doesn't show at all. How can I debug such a problem?

Comment: what do yo mean by "it is not displayed like the other tabs" ?

Comment: @H.NiK I mean it is not displayed at all.

Comment: Have you assigned the quicktabs block to any region?

Comment: @H.NiK The other tabs do show, so that is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the view I had assigned to that tab did not work (I don't know why). Still, I am surprised that the tab itself wouldn't show just because the view is broken.. Whatever, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the quicktab block to a particular region. Then you might be able to see the tabs